# How to make the strip text in 1 row?

Tags: r, ggplot2, strip, facet-wrap

a part of my facet-wrap command structure contains this:

```
facet_wrap(scales= "free",day~type~cellline)
```

and the strips I got spread in 3 lines and make up a lot of space so I want them just in 1 line. (DAY1 K562 Parent) 
How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Does `facet_wrap(scales= "free", ~paste(day, type, cellline))` get what you want?

Comment: Yes, it works, that's awesome. Thanks a lot :) . But I come up with a new question that is, you see now I have the same tag "Day 1 Parent" for all the strips, how can I have just 1 in the center of the 5 panels?

Comment: Apologies for the self-promotion, but I've written a function for this in my own package (it's not on CRAN)  You could do `facet_nested(scales = "free", ~ paste(day, type) + cellline)`, I'd think. See https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x.

Comment: Not at all, no worries! I really appreciate your help. I believe it will work but I need time to learn how to use that function. it's great of your work! Thanks a lot!!!